# Algorithm(!= linear search) to find the first number less than X in an array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, search, binary-search

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the first number less than X in an array of integers. Actually I'm using linear search,but I think that binary search may be better(as I already have seen sometime ago) but I don't know how to implement it myself(not implement a modified version to find the first-less than X). If there is something better than bin search,please tell me. I need of it because this array is so-much accessed and modified while the program is running.

Here's the current(trival) implementation:

```
int findmin(int *arr,int n,int size)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size && arr[i] < n; i++)
    ;
  return i-1;
}
```

This index is used the parameter input to function that insert N-value in a specific index. The index of this function and insert a number in array but still make it sorted without a sort() call at each time a new number is inserted. 
It is a relevant file text parsing,parse much files and I a number considerable of characters. I need to make some effort to make the things more fast as possible(in my context and knowlege).

**EDIT:** The array is sorted always will be,even after insections of new numbers.

Comment: If the integers aren't sorted, you can't really do better than linear search.

Comment: @isbadawi: the array is sorted. I forget to say it. See update.

Comment: To keep your array sorted, do the binary search for the element you're about to insert, then insert the element at the found location.

Comment: Jack, I'm curious what the numbers you are sorting actually mean. You say that it is relevant to text file parsing, but I can't think what kind of operation requires sorting integers. If you can give us a little more detail on the actual operation you're performing and satisfy my curiosity on this puzzle, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @beaker:This number are hash-like.I'm writing a parsing that take some keywords,get its hash,and insert into a sorted array of integers.I need to do a lot of request in this array,I use bsearch for perfomance,where the array needs to be sorted.I have several anothers functions and algorithms that works  on this array,and again,for perfomance quetions need to be sorted(always)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for indulging my curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary search is no problem here. The difficult is how to check the boundary conditions and what value should be returned. Moreover, you have to take care of duplicate values. The following function will work.

```
    int binarySearch(int a[], int length, int value)
    {
        if (a[0] > value)
            return -1;

        int low = 0;
        int high = length-1;

        while (low<=high)
        {
            int mid = low+((high-low)/2);

            if(a[mid] >= value)
                high = mid-1;
            else
                low = mid+1;
        }

        return low-1;
    }
```

---

**Test**: (with duplicates)

```
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 10};
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int index = binarySearch(arr, length, 6); // will be 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the array of N elements already sorted.

Set "high" to N and "low" to -1.

"Probe" element N/2 (rounding down to an int).

If the probed element is < your target, set "high" to N/2.  If >, set "low" to N/2.  (If ==, of course, then you have your answer.)

Repeat, probing halfway between "low" and "high".

There are boundary conditions you need to worry about, but not too complicated.